# Wiring car lift with 3 wires to 4 wire plug

Tags: electrical

I just installed a lift in my workshop, the lift needs 220v power supply and has 2 hots/1 ground. I have a 4 wire 220 plug in the shop, wondering if I can wire a 4 wire plug to the lift by just not using the neutral connection?

Answer (score 8):

It's fine to have an adapter that lets a 3-prong PLUG go into a 4-prong SOCKET -so long as the amps of plug and socket are the same. You should be able buy UL-Listed pre-made adapters which do exactly that.  The reverse would very bad and for instance would set an RV on fire lol.

Motors are weird. Check your documentation for the breaker size required for your car lift.  Sometimes you motor allows a larger breaker because the motor has its own overload protection.  If so, the plug can match the permitted breaker. (e.g. a 15A motor might allow a 30A breaker in which case a 30A plug is allowed on it).

Note that socket size must ALWAYS match breaker size.  (except a 50A socket is allowed on 40A breakers since no 40A sockets are made, and 15A sockets *plural* are allowed on 20A breakers for convenience. All 15A sockets are internally rated for 20A pass-thru.)

Other than what I just said, if you have a *larger amp*  socket and need to adapt to a *smaller amp* plug, that is also possible, get an adapter to do this which is UL Listed.  It will have an internal fuse for safety (the fuse may be molded in and be non-replaceable).

Comment: Workshop, not an RV.

Comment: @Technophile OP might plug an RV into the large socket in the workshop.

Comment: Or, @Technophile, a future owner of the residence.

Comment: OP starts "I just installed a lift in my workshop".

Comment: @Technophile I edited yesterday after your comment. We all unerstand. The reason for that sentence is the rest of the paragraph is a broad, sweeping statement about adapters, and it needs qualifying.  "Teach a man to fish" is kinda my thing.  The vast majority of viewers of this Q&A will be people finding it via search engines, and won't have a lift *particularly*.

Answer (score 7):

Neutral is not needed for that lift, so not using it is perfectly okay.

Just make sure that you do use ground with no mixups(reverse neutral and ground).

It might be better to change the receptacle to a NEMA 6(hot,hot, ground) and cap the neutral inside of the box, if the receptacle is not used for other machines.

Comment: Is there a good reason why the 4-pin receptacle should not be used?